# PHP - __call all the time

Tags: php, methods, call, magic-methods

Say we have a class with several protected and/or public methods.
I need to perform a check each time a method is called. I could do that check each time i call a method :

```
class Object
{
    // Methods
}

$o = new Object();

if($mayAccess) $o->someMethod();
```

or

```
if($mayAccess) $this->someMethod();
```

But i would like developers neither to have to think about it nor to write it. I've thought about using __call to do :

```
class Object
{
    public function __call($methodName, $args)
    {
        if($mayAccess) call_user_func_array($this->$methodName, $args);
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly, if i call the method from inside the class, __call will not invoked as it only works when a non-visible method is called.

Is there a clean way to hide this check for both internal and external calls ? Again the goal is to make sure a developper won't forget to do it when calling a method.

Thanks in advance :)

```
EDIT :
```

I have another way of doing this :

```
class Object
{
    public function __call($methodName, $args)
    {
        if($mayAccess) call_user_func_array($methodName, $args);
    }
}

function someMethod() { }
```

But i won't be able to use $this anymore, which means no protected methods, which i do need.

Comment: Please have a look to the [call_user_func_array](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) manual page. I corrected 3 times the same mistake in this single post : if you want a method to be callable, you must use `array($object, $method)` to describe it.

Comment: @Ninsuo Don't do that. You absolutely should not be correcting the code in a question. The code as posted by the person asking the question needs to remain as it was written.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, I dont think so. What you could do though is write a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern):

```
class MayAccessProxy {

    private $_obj;

    public function __construct($obj) {
        $this->_obj = $obj;
    }

    public function __call($methodName, $args) {
        if($mayAccess) call_user_func_array(array($this->_obj, $methodName), $args);
    }
}
```

This means you have to instantiate a proxy for every object you want to check:

```
$obj = new MayAccessProxy(new Object());
$obj->someMethod();
```

Ofcourse you'd also want the proxy to behave exactly like the object itself. So you also have to define the other magic methods.

To make it a bit easier for the developers you could do something like this:

```
class Object {

    /**
     * Not directly instanciable.
     */
    private __construct() {}  

    /**
     * @return self
     */
    public static function createInstance() {
        $obj = new MayAccessProxy(new self());
        return $obj;
    }
}

$obj = Object::createInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This still involes the developpers to think about the proxy and write it, so i should maybe think about another way to do this.

Comment: Problem is, you don't *have* to instantiate these proxy objects -- you can still just use that `new Object()` directly.  So this still puts it on the developers to remember to always create/use a proxy.  Not exactly onerous, but still a bit error-prone...

Comment: If you're going to include a named constructor, you probably want to ensure that the real constructor is not public.  That'd go a long way toward preventing naked Objects from floating around.

Comment: This is not the Singleton pattern.  Just so you know.  :)  It's just a named constructor.

Comment: Really? What is that in such a case?

Comment: You had a pretty decent answer. Why did you changed it into `static` hell :( (P.S. that's not a singleton as @cHao noted)

Comment: What is a nammed constructor ? Like in C++ ? And what would be the syntax for using one please ?

Comment: A "named constructor" is just a static member function that returns a new instance of its class.  So instead of saying `new Object`, you'd say `Object::createInstance()`.  And yes, it's just like in C++.

Comment: +1 @cHao, thanks for pointing it out (reviewed what was a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern))

Comment: Oh i see, i already used that without even knowing it was called this way. ANd it would also allow me not to store a reference to the object to call one of it's methods. Thanks. I think this just solved my problem, i'm going to try.

Comment: @Virus721 What is your real problem here? Developers will forget about asking for permission. They will forget about adding the proxy. They will forget about anything you think about because the data will still be accessible somehow - developers will write their own code if they need access and you do not allow it. There is nothing you can do to stop them, unless you make it easy for them to do the right thing and harder to do the wrong thing - which might end up in not giving them the object in the first place if they do not have permission.

Comment: This "Object" is in fact the controller (a singleton) of my website. Its methods are called depending on the value of an HTTP variable in GET or POST, OR by the developpers from inside one of it's methods. For exemple, when trying to log in, the method "submitLogin" will be called by the visitor throught the action of the form and "submitLogin" will then call the method "viewLoginForm" in case of failure. I need to restrict access to some methods depending on the rights the visitor is granted to prevent him from performing certain actions or viewing certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

So what if you made all your methods protected or private? (I know this is old and "answered" question)

The __call magic method intercepts all non-existing and non-public methods so having all your methods not public will allow you to intercepts all of them.

```php
public function __call( $func, $args )
{
  if ( !method_exists( $this, $func ) ) throw new Error("This method does not exist in this class.");

  Handle::eachMethodAction(); // action which will be fired each time a method will be called

  return $this->$func( ...$args );
}
```

Thanks to that you will not need to do anything to your code (expect adding __call and doing quick `replace all`) and if your classes have common parent then you can just add it to parent and not care anymore.

## BUT

This solution creates two major problems:

- The protected/private methods automatically will be available to public
- The errors will be pointing to __call not the proper file

### What can we do?

#### Custom private/protected

You can add a list of all protected/private methods and check before the call if the method can be return to public:

```php
public function __call( $func, $args )
{
  $private = [
    "PrivateMethod" => null
  ];

  if ( !method_exists( $this, $func ) ) throw new Error("This method does not exist in this class.");
  if ( isset( $private[$func] )       ) throw new Error("This method is private and cannot be called");

  Handle::eachMethodAction(); // action which will be fired each time a method will be called

  return $this->$func( ...$args );
}
```

For many this might be deal breaker, but I personally use this approach only in classes with only public methods (which I set to protected). So if you can, you might separate methods into `publicClass` and `privateClass` and eliminate this problem.

#### Custom Errors and Stack

For better errors I have created this method:

```php
/**
  *    Get parent function/method details
  *
  *    @param int counter [OPT] The counter allows to move further back or forth in search of methods detalis
  *
  *    @return array trace It contains those elements :
  *       - function - name of the function
  *       - file     - in which file exception happend
  *       - line     - on which line
  *       - class    - in which class
  *       - type     - how it was called
  *       - args     - arguments passed to function/method
  */

protected function getParentMethod( int $counter = 0 ) {
  $excep = new \Exception();
  $trace = $excep->getTrace();
  $offset = 1;
  if ( sizeof( $trace ) < 2 ) $offset = sizeof( $trace ) - 1;
  return $trace[$offset - $counter];
}
```

Which will return details about the previous method/function which called protected method.

```php
public function __call( $func, $args )
{
  $private = [
    "PrivateMethod" => null
  ];

  if ( !method_exists( $this, $func ) ) {
    $details = (object) $this->getParentMethod();
    throw new Error("Method $func does not exist on line " . $details->line . ", file: " . $details->file . " invoked by " . get_class($this) . $details->type . $func . " () ");
  }

  if ( isset($private[$func]) ) {
    $details = (object) $this->getParentMethod();
    throw new Error("Method $func is private and cannot be called on line " . $details->line . ", file: " . $details->file . " invoked by " . get_class($this) . $details->type . $func . " () ");
  }

  return $this->$func( ...$args );
}
```

This is not much of a problem but might lead to some confusion while debugging.

### Conclusion

This solution allows you to have control over any call of private/protected methods FROM OUTSIDE OF CLASS. Any `this->Method` will omit `__call` and will normally call private/protected method.

```php
class Test {
  
  public function __call( $func, $args )
  {
    echo "__call! ";
    if ( !method_exists( $this, $func ) ) throw new Error("This method does not exist in this class.");

    return $this->$func( ...$args );
  }

  protected function Public()
  {
    return "Public";
  }

  protected function CallPublic()
  {
    return "Call->" . $this->Public();
  }

}

$_Test = new Test();
echo $_Test->CallPublic(); // result: __call! Call->Public - it uses two methods but __call is fired only once
```

If you want to add a similar thing to static methods use `__callStatic` magic method.